Extension of lifetime for inner fields when the type's lifetime is extended?
I am pondering about a piece of tooling code that we were using for a while here now, but which I suspect is actual undefined behaviour (at least, I got a couple of debugging sessions where it looks like references to dangling memory issues).
The problem is the following piece of code:
template<class T>
struct NonNullCollection
{
    const std::vector<T*>& Array;
    struct It
    {
        It() = delete;
        It(const std::vector<T*>& InArray, size_t InIndex = 0) : Array(InArray), Index(InIndex) {}
        const std::vector<T*>& Array;
        size_t Index;
        It operator++() { Index++; FindNextNonNull(); return *this; }
        It& FindNextNonNull() { while (Index < Array.size() && !Array[Index]) Index++; return *this; }
        bool operator!=(It it) const { return Index != it.Index; }
        T* operator*() const { return Array[Index]; }
    };
    It begin() const { return Array.size() == 0 ? end() : It{Array, 0}.FindNextNonNull(); }
    It end() const { return It{Array, Array.size()}; }
};
template<typename T> auto NonNull(const std::vector<T*>& array) { return NonNullCollection<T>{array}; }

The "NonNull" function is usually used in range-based for loops to filter out nullptr entries in the array. I am having some weird issues when I use that passing temporary objects from function returns. For example:
std::vector<MyClass*> GetSomeArray() { ... }
...
for (MyClass* c : NonNull(GetSomeArray())) { ... }

Now I am trying to break that apart to verify whether its OK or whether I have some dangling references and undefined behaviour here.
From my understanding, the for-loop is basically exactly the same as this, right?
{
    auto&& collection = NonNull(GetSomeArray());
    auto&& end = collection.end();
    for (auto&& it = collection.begin(); it != end; ++it) { ... }
}

The NonNull(...) part returns an temporary of type "NonNullCollection". As its bound to a reference, its lifetime is extended until the end of the for loop, right?
But what about the lifetime of the temporary "std::vector<MyClass*>" returned by GetSomeArray(). Its lifetime is definitely extended until the end of the NonNull() call. But is it guaranteed to be valid as long as "collection" here is alive as well?
Greetings, Imi.
Edit: Also, (if I am right with my suspicion), I was wondering whether anything changes if I am not calling the NonNull function but instead using NonNullCollection{...} directly.
std::vector<MyClass*> GetSomeArray() { ... }
...
for (MyClass* c : NonNullCollection<UMyClass>{GetSomeArray()}) { ... }

This gets rid of one of the temporary objects, but still holds a const reference to a temporary object inside a type which is extended by itself. On the other hand, that type is no longer generated by the NonNull function, so its existence might be guaranteed to be extended until the end of the for loop?
{
    // NonNullCollection<MyClass>{...} is not a function call, so does that extend the return of GetSomeArray until the end of the for loop?
    auto&& collection = NonNullCollection<MyClass>{GetSomeArray()};
    auto&& end = collection.end();
    for (auto&& it = collection.begin(); it != end; ++it) { ... }
}


In auto&& collection = NonNull(GetSomeArray()); there are 2 temporary objects, the vector returned by GetSomeArray() and the pr-value returned by NonNull(). Only the second one r-referenced by collection has its life extended. Same for auto&& collection = NonNullCollection<MyClass>{GetSomeArray()};, only the pr-value NonNullCollection<MyClass> is extended. Only in the initial for loop, the full expression NonNull(GetSomeArray()) is guarantied valid by the standard "The lifetime of some temporaries in the for-range-initializer is extended to cover the entire loop (6.7.7).".
